# Interview question -- apparent duplicate in a Set

Tags: java, set

I was shown this code during a recent interview.

```
class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

Set<User> set = new HashSet<>();
User user = new User();
user.setId(1L);
user.setName("test");
set.add(user);

User user2 = new User();
user2.setId(1L);
user2.setName("test");
set.add(user2);

System.out.println(set.size());
```

The interviewer asked me what would be printed out for the size of the set.  I answered 1, since both instances of User have identical values.  But after the interview I ran the code, and I got 2.  Since sets are supposed to have unique values, can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: `User` doesn't override `equals` and `hashCode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default implementation of equals() method would compare two objects memory addresses and default implementation of hashCode() method would will be object's memory address. As we're creating 2 objects pointing to different memory locations, they will be different by default, unless we define the equality and hash code by overriding the 2 methods for the class. But if you try to add the same instance twice, there will only be one instance added to the set. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Slaw for the answer -- `User` doesn't override `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: It is also a good practice to override compareTo by implementing Comparable interface as Treeset doesn't use the equals method.

Comment: @javapedia.net You should only implement `Comparable` if the object has a _natural_ order (which `User` might). Besides, you could always use a custom `Comparator` with `TreeSet`. (Note: OP's example uses a `HashSet`).